# How would I create a web based dynamic mind mapping application in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, graphics, mindmapping

I am trying to create a type of mind mapping software that runs on the web, and I am trying to figure out where to start.  I would like this to be able to be used by the most number of people possible.  My web application is currently written using Javascript for the front end and C# for the back-end.

I was thinking of using Javascript for this.  Unfortunately, the most experience I have with Javascript is with basic DOM manipulating using JQuery and cannot really figure out how I would create mind map bubbles with interactive elements inside of them.

There are one or two mind mapping jquery plugins I have found but all don't function the way I need to (too much animation, slow, doesn't look easy to add and remove elements easily, doesn't work in IE, etc...) so I am looking at creating my own system but I have no idea how I would even approach this type of thing with JS.

HTML5 is not an option as it looks to be low availability at this point.

Comment: I think you're going to have to narrow down your question a little, or at least describe the problem in more basic detail for those of us who don't automatically know what "mind map bubbles" mean for a web UI.

Comment: I pretty much need a system that can dynamically render a collection of circles that can be connected to each other.  I also need text and other elements to be able to be interacted with inside of these.  It's a graphical way to show how ideas relate to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) in combination with the [Dracula Graph Library](http://dracula.ameisenbar.de/) will get you started.
Be prepared to do some scripting of your own. (for example: i quickly checked the source of the dracula graph library. The graph has no method removeNode, but it is really easy to add it )

Comment: That actually looks perfect, with a lot of browser compatibility.  Thanks!